# Is there a way to bring lists and variables through a file import in python?

Tags: python-3.x

So, the title may seem vague, so I'm going to describe it in more detail here. I'm writing a space-themed text-based game as a project, and I've reached various problems. I'm trying to use multiple files to simply everything, and so, say I have these variables in file 1:

```
player_health = 100

o2 = 100
```

And that's fine and it works and all, but in the first file I have, I have an ever-growing check() function available (so the player can see game info), so I made another file to handle loops. In the second file, I have this, for example:

```
while True:
    if o2 == 0:
        time.sleep(2)
        player_health = player_health -1
```

and for the player,

```
 while True:
     if player_health = 0
     print(game_over)
```

Right now, o2 and player_health are set to 100 as variables. Game_over is a string I made, but that doesn't really matter currently. I defined o2 and player_health in file 1, say, and when I import file 2, they don't seem to work any more. Remember the While loops are handled in File 2. I could just put it all in one file, but then It would be harder for me to bugfix. The reason I'm doing this is so that I can handle the start and the loops and the actual story part separately, and add or remove loops as I see fit without having to sift through tons of code, like I would probably have to if it was all in a single file.

There's a lot of source code, So I'll just post snippets from file one and two. If you want to see all of the source code from both files, I could post it somehow, but there would be a lot.

**File One Snippets:**

```
(This is at the beginning of file one, which is named VortexA)
o2 = 100
nitrogen = 100
ship_store = []
player_inv = [] #These Lists and variables handle levels of life support and storage.
air = [o2, nitrogen]
ship_weapons = []
currency = 5
power = 0
He_3  = 0 
ship_health = 0
player_health = 100
ship = False

(This is at the end of file one. Just adding it here)
print("Type start(game) to begin")
game = 1
def start(variable):
    if game == 1: # This starts the game. Don't want everything in one file.
        import vortexB
```

**File 2 (vortexB) Snippets**

I already posted some of the loops using variables above, but I'll post the errors I get here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
start(game)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Python Stuff\Python Game\vortexa.py", line 87,  in start
import vortexb
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Python Stuff\Python Game\vortexb.py", line 25, in <module>
print(player_health)
NameError: name 'player_health' is not defined
```

**TL;DR:**
Basically, I don't know if it's possible to import variables into another python file through the

```
import file
```

function. I'm trying to keep my game simple and easy to fix if something goes wrong by having separate files to handle loops and story.. If that's possible. If it's not, I'm going to have one hell of a messy file...

I'm just going to have the first file handle a tutorial-type thing, the second handle loops, and the third handle game-play elements.The way I want it set up is so that the variables are declared during a tutorial, and then the loops are in effect, and then I want the actual game to start. I feel like I'm missing something really simple, or what I'm trying to do is impossible. I strongly feel that it's something to do with o2 and nitrogen being stored in the air list, but that doesn't really explain player_health not being able to work. If it won't work at all, I'll see if there is another way to do it, like putting it all in one file.

Thanks in advance. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually *tried* to `import` it? And what happened?

Comment: Yeah. At the end of Vortexa, there's an import statement that takes you to Vortexb. My problem is that the variable's don't seem to be "persistent" across.

Comment: Oh I see; you're doing it the wrong way around. You need to import *from* `Vortexa` to access the variables defined there, *in* `Vortexb`.

Comment: Ah, so first I'd do import vortexb, then import vortexa to get the variables from it? Or should I make a new file containing the variables and then import it to each?

Comment: The first of those would be a circular import. Just `import Vortexa` at the start of `Vortexb`. However, note that this seems to be crying out for OOP (e.g. `Ship` and `Player` classes, etc).

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I was going to need classes. I'm yet to learn about those from the books I'm reading, but thanks for the insight- I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it sounds like you need [a separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

As for the title of this article goes, yes. You can import variables (lists, strings, objects, etc.) from specific files.

If you have a file `constants.py`:

```
class Player:
    health = 100
    power = 12
    # etc

    def __init__(self, name, power):
        self.name = name
        if power:
            self.power = power

    @property
    def is_ded(self):
        if self.health < 0:
            return True
        return False
```

And then inside of `battle.py`:

```
from constants import Player

me = Player('Kris', 500)
mic = Player('A microphone', 0)

def do_battle(player1, player2):
    player1.health = player1.health - player2.power
    player2.health = player2.health - player1.power

do_battle(me, mic)

mic.is_ded
# >>>True
me.is_ded
# >>>False
```

This is built into Python. Congratulations for picking the best language.